# Using transitive to prove symmetric

Tags: relations

Consider a relation R on a set A. Prove R is symmetric if R is transitive and there exists a c in A such that for every x in A, xRc and cRx. Help!!

Comment: Take $x$ and $y$ in $A$. Then if $x$~$y$ then $y$~$c$ and $c$~$x$ then by transitivity; $y$~$x$

Comment: Here is a [mathjax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). Be sure to show your work.

Answer (score 0):

Assume $x,y\in A$ and $xRy$. We must show that $yRx$. We know that $xRc$ and $cRy$, by assumption. Since R is transitive we have $xRc \land cRy \rightarrow yRx$, proving that R is symmetric.

Comment: @Arthur I had. It is corrected now.